# I keep getting HTML5 syntax errors with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Are these kind of errors valid and how can I resolve. Doesn't HTML5 allow this code?

```
<button title="" disabled="disabled" >&gt;&gt;</button>
```

Validation: (HTML5) - the values permitted for this attribute do not include 'disabled'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83) that improves html5/css3 validation and intellisense support.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to change my Text-Editor preferences to get VS to recognize the HTML5 controls (for others that arrive here via Google like me).

In VS, go to Tools > Options and select TextEditor/HTML/Validation on the left pane, then select HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` is a valid html5 property for `button`.  However, you should always specify `type` on buttons, as different browsers use different defaults.  Validation may be reporting that omission in a roundabout way.

Comment: I added type but syntax highlighting still complains.